# Split dataframe according with the same previous values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two lists that represent a source and a target. I would like to isolate the same values even if it is about the same source or even if a target seems to be source too.
For example, I want to isolate the dataframe of the picture as depicted.40 is the same source and I want to keep it, and also 41 is a source that was target in the previous lines.
My initial idea is to compare the values with previous items but that does not work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCNKo.jpg)

```
source = [40, 40, 40, 41, 42, 50, 51, 101]
target = [76, 77, 41, 79, 80, 51, 90, 102]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(source, target)),
              columns=['source','target'])

sourcelist=[]
targetlist=[]
for i in range(len(source)):
    if (source[i] == source[i+1]) or (source[i+1] in targetlist):
        sourcelist.append(source[i])
        targetlist.append(target[i])   
    else:  
        break
```

My code returns sourcelist=[40,40] and targetlist=[76,77] instead of sourcelist=[40,40,40,41] and targetlist=[76,77,41,79]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the result you tried to achieve. I edited some parts of your code to make the split as mentioned in the sample your provided.

```
source = [40, 40, 40, 41, 42, 50, 51, 101]
target = [76, 77, 41, 79, 80, 51, 90, 102]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(source, target)),
              columns=['source','target'])

sourcelist=[]
targetlist=[]
output=[]
for i in range(1, len(source) + 1):
    sourcelist.append(source[i-1])
    targetlist.append(target[i-1])
    if (i == len(source)) or not ((source[i-1] == source[i]) or (source[i] in targetlist)):
      output.append({
          'source_list': sourcelist,
          'target_list': targetlist
      })
      sourcelist = []
      targetlist = []
```

The output will be as below:

```
[
     {'source_list': [40, 40, 40, 41], 'target_list': [76, 77, 41, 79]},
     {'source_list': [42], 'target_list': [80]},
     {'source_list': [50, 51], 'target_list': [51, 90]},
     {'source_list': [101], 'target_list': [102]}
]
```